# Windows batch comparing strings with case sensitivity

Tags: windows, if-statement, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to compare a string that needs to be a case-sensitive compare in a DOS batch script.  I cannot figure out how to turn ON the case sensitivity in a IF statement.  Here is what I am doing and it is also matching on a lower case "-f", which I am trying to avoid:

```
SET "ARGS=%*"
IF "%ARGS:-F=%" NEQ "%ARGS%" (
  ECHO Pro option -F was found and not allowed.
  GOTO :ERROR
)
```

Comment: The DOS `IF` statement *is* case-sensitive by default; it should only be case-insensitive with the `/I` switch.  Have you echoed the values of `"!%ARGS%:-F=!"` and `"!%ARGS%!"` before your `IF` statement to see what they hold?

Comment: That sounds odd, as EQ and NEQ (and ==) are case-sensitive by default, unless the "/i" flag is specified.

Comment: More specifically, the error I was getting was "character ( was unexpected" or a message similar to that.  This message was resolved by replacing 'NEQ' with the 'NOT ==' method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your IF statement *is* properly performing a case sensitive search. The problem is your expansion search and replace is corrupted, as Endoro has pointed out, and the correct form `"!ARGS:-F=!"` is case *insensitive*. While expanding ARGS, it first looks for `-F`, disregarding case, and replaces it with nothing.

Unfortunately, that is how search and replace works. There is no method to make it case sensitive.

You could use the following to do a case sensitive test:

```
echo(!ARGS!|find "-F" >nul && echo Pro option -F was found.
```

Comment: I created a unit test that proves this answer.  Thanks.  https://gist.github.com/djangofan/5767940

Answer (score 8):

Use `IF /I` for simplicity ... the `/I` switch, if specified, means do case insensitive string compares.

```
SET "ARGS=%*"
IF /I "%ARGS:-F=%" NEQ "%ARGS%" (
  ECHO Pro option -F was found and not allowed.
  GOTO :ERROR
)
```

Additionally, it is common practice to use `==` instead of `NEQ` because the later is used for numeric comparisons.

i.e.

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (ECHO.Ok.)
```

Comment: Are you sure about using `==` instead of `NEQ`? As far as I know, `NEQ` is "Not EQual to" and `==` is "EQUal to"?

Answer (score 2):

Please look at my examples and the output (call `<script> -F`):

```
@echo off &setlocal 
SET "ARGS=%*"
echo "%ARGS%"
echo "%ARGS:-F=%"

"-F"
""
```

your version:

```
@echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET "ARGS=%*"
echo "%ARGS%"
echo "!%ARGS%:-F=!"

"-F"
"-F="
```

Comment: I don't need to read a scripting book.  This mistake is something anyone could make.  Thanks for figuring out the problem for me.

Comment: +1, good catch with the corrupted search and replace syntax, but that does not help solve case insensitive issue. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17033165/1012053)

Answer (score 1):

```
IF "%args:-F=-F%"=="%args%" (ECHO no sign of -f) ELSE (echo -f detected)
```

Should work for you - it does for me!

---

Interesting result.

Here's my test routine:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
CALL :test something -f
CALL :test something -F
CALL :test -f
CALL :test -F
GOTO :eof
:test
ECHO testing %*
SET "args=%*"
IF "%args:-F=-F%"=="%args%" (ECHO no sign of -f) ELSE (echo -f detected)
GOTO :EOF
```

And results:

```
testing something -f
-f detected
testing something -F
no sign of -f
testing -f
-f detected
testing -F
no sign of -f
```

So - works for me. Perhaps it's version-dependent. I'm using W7/64.

Comment: Just in case anyone wants to know _why_ this works ... the `%args:-F=-F%` does a case-insensitive search for `-F` and replaces it with the upper case `-F`.  Then the `if` statement case-sensitively compares it to the unmodified `%args%`.